# Null Pointer Exception in an Array of Strings

Tags: java, string, nullpointerexception

I am creating a shadow of createTriangle() in the method createPathingTriangle().  createTriangle worked just fine, but when I created the identically-dimensioned createPathingTriangle that used String instead of int, the new triangle started throwing NPE's.

The line that's throwing it is-

```
pathingTriangle[y][x] = new String("00" + String.valueOf(x));
```

i.e. the first line that populates it.  I looked it up and have liberally sprinkled "new" around the code in createPathingTriangle, but it didn't seem to solve the problem..  I am assuming that it has something to do with the fact that int is a primitive but String is not, but hours of fiddling and nothing gives.

```
private int[][] createTriangle() {
    triangle = new int[triangleSize][];
    for (int y = 0; y < triangle.length; y++){
        int [] xAxis = new int[triangle.length - y];
        for (int x = 0; x < xAxis.length; x++){
            xAxis[x] = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
        }
        triangle[y] = xAxis;
    }
    printTriangle(triangle);
    return triangle;
}

private String[][] createPathingTriangle() {
    pathingTriangle = new String[triangleSize][];

    for (int y = 0; y < pathingTriangle.length; y++){
        for (int x = 0; x < pathingTriangle.length - y; x++){
            if (x < 10){
                pathingTriangle[y][x] = new String("00" + String.valueOf(x));
            }
            else if (x < 100){
                pathingTriangle[y][x] = new String("0" + String.valueOf(x));
            }
            else{
                pathingTriangle[y][x] = new String(String.valueOf(x));
            }
        }
    }
    return pathingTriangle;
}
```

Comment: Can you post a stacktrace?

Comment: Please mark a line where NPE occur

Comment: First of all don't use `new String();` as you create new `String` objects unnecessarily. Second can you provide some stack trace  and more information

Comment: The code is not the same for `String` and `int`, in the `int` code, you are correctly creating `int` arrays (`int [] xAxis = new int[triangle.length - y];`), and using them, but not in the `String` code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never initialize the second dimension of the array `pathingTriangle = new String[triangleSize][];`

which is done in the first funnction here `int [] xAxis = new int[triangle.length - y];`

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I reverted the code back to that, and it all worked out somehow.  What's weird is that I had originally just copied and pasted the code, and replaced int with String and it didn't just work from the get-go.